# Understanding a symbolic addition question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the below addition A, B, C, D, E, F, and G represent the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. If each variable has a different value, and E ≠ 0, then G equals what?

[image]

Actually I haven't understood the question. Can you please rephrase it for me? Each digit has a different value means?

Comment: "Each variable has a different value", right? The letters A to G has different values in the range 0-6. Two letters cant have the same value.

Comment: Start to think about what E can be given its non zero. The sum AB+CD has a maximum of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find values for $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ such that the addition holds. In other words $AB+CD=EFG$. For example $A=1, B=2, C=3,D=4,E=5, F=6, G=0$, then you have $AB + CD = 12+34 = 560 = EFG$, which is obviously not true ($12+34=46$), so the values we chose for $A,\ldots, G$ were not right.

*each variable/digit (since it is the same thing here) has a different value* means you are not allowed to use any digit from $0-6$ more than once (also since you have $7$ numbers and exactly $7$ positions/digits you will use each exactly once), e.g. $A= 1 = C$.

**Hint**
$AB, CD$ are two digit numbers, so immediately we have upper boundary $AB+CD < 198$ (setting $AB=CD=99$), but we can set it even lower, having only number $0-6$ and not repeating the biggest number we can get is $64+53 = 117.$ But that has repeating digits, so we can go even lower with the upper bound to $106$ (since $7,8,9$ are not allowed).

On the other end, the lowest possible two digit is $02+13=15$ (or $03+12$ does not matter), but then would $E=0$ (and we get more than one contradiction with that). Again, we can make it better, since $E=1$ we get $100<AB+CD$ (so we could've skipped the part about $02+13$). And the smallest three-digit number with different values is $102$, so we have $102<AB+CD<106$.

Answer (score 0):

62+43=105

each variable has a different value means no two variables can take same integral value.